# Calling a function within beforeShowDay in datepicker , javascript issue

Tags: javascript, datepicker

The idea behind this code is that i want to set some date, which will be disabled in my datepicker. If I leave in this format: `beforeShowDay: editDays,` , it works. BUT I want leave in this format: `beforeShowDay: function(dt) {` and call the function editDays there!. But as you can see in my code, it doesn't work. Actually i don't know how do i call the function. Can you help me to make this work ? This is my javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./actions/ajax/actiongetallfreedays.php",
        async: false
    });
    var freedays = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
    var disabledDates  = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < freedays.length; i++){
        split = freedays[i].free_day.split("-");
        disabledDates[i] = split[0]+"/"+split[1]+"/"+split[2];
    }

    function editDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < disabledDates.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(disabledDates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {             
                 return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    } 
});
```

and this my main function:

```
function initDatePicker(cls, minDate, maxDate, beforeshowday) {
    beforeshowday = beforeshowday == "1" ? beforeshowday : "0";

    $(cls).datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
                if (beforeshowday == 0) {
                    return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 || dt.getDay() == 3 || dt.getDay() == 4 || dt.getDay() == 5, ""];
                } else {
                    return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
                }
                editDays();
            },
            //   beforeShowDay: editDays,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: minDate,
            maxDate: maxDate,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            date: $(cls).val(),
            current: $(cls).val(),
            starts: 1,
            onBeforeShow: function() {
                $(cls).DatePickerSetDate($(cls).val(), true);
            },
            onChange: function(formated) {
                $(cls).val(formated);
                $(cls).DatePickerHide();
            }

        })
        .attr("readonly", "readonly");

}
```

Comment: return editdays() method before return statement. Just because return statement placed inside if condition and editDays method call in the last, this function won't come into picture. Second, editdays method needs a parameter which is missing in method call

Answer (score 0):

Function `editDays()` is not called because you return from the anonymous function in any case

```
beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
        if (beforeshowday == 0) {
            return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 || dt.getDay() == 3 || dt.getDay() == 4 || dt.getDay() == 5, ""];
        }
        else {
            return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
        }
       // actually should be calling editDays like this here, but it never reaches
        return editDays(dt);
    },
```

Comment: it is not work neither you example. But how can change the editDays in order to keep the conditions?

Comment: You've got lots of code and it's up to to come up with correct logic. I pointed out the place where you apply static (unchangeable rules) to filter out dates. And as result skip `editDays` which applies dynamic logic: filtering out dates arrived from ajax request. However, from your current snippet it looks like `editDates` is not even accessible in `initDatePicker` because it was defined inside `ready` handler. So... if you create a jsfiddle/plunker and describe desired behavior I can fix it there